# fetch subsequent data in one go in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

following is my schema where one user has assigned specific orders and one order could have multiple items

```
Master JSON
-----------
users
    user-id
        email
        username

orders
    order-id
        orderNo
        orderStatus
        deliveryDate

items
    item-id
        itemNo
        itemName
        itemQty
        itemPrice

Related JSON    
------------
    user-orders
        user-id
            order-id                
                orderNo
                orderStatus
                deliveryDate

    order-itmes
        order-id
            item-id
                itemNo
                itemName
                itemQty
                itemPrice
```

i am accessing all orders belong to one user as follows

```
dbRef.child("user-orders").child(userId);
```

and updating listview as follows inside `ChildEventListener`

```
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Order order = dataSnapshot.getValue(Order.class);
            listview.add(order);
            adapter.notifyParentItemInserted(listview.size()-1);

        }
```

but at the same time i want to fetch all items belong to all orders as well , hence i need to use following query inside `onChildAdded` and will be needing another `ChildEventListener` listener.

```
dbRef.child("order-items").child(dataSnapshot.getKey());/ /key of newly fetched order.
```

so question is , firebase has any way to fetch all items belong to all orders inside one listener ? like if i pass all order keys in one go to fetch all items belong to those orders.

i am displaying order and items details on one list only hence i need both data in one go

EDIT

calling orders

```
 public void readOrders(String userId){

        mOrderQuery = mDatabaseRef.child("user-orders").child(userId);
        mOrderQuery.addChildEventListener(mOrderEventListener);

    }
```

Listener to read orders

```
private ChildEventListener mOrderEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Order order = dataSnapshot.getValue(Order.class);
            orderList.add(order);
            // fetching items belong to specific order 
            mItemQuery = mDatabaseRef.child("order-items").child(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            // problem is here for every order i have to register a event listener and this not the right way to do it 
            mItemQuery.addChildEventListener(mItemEventListener);


        }

        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG , "onCancelled called");
        }
    };
```

Listener to read items

```
private ChildEventListener mItemEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Item item = dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
           // here i need to map the incoming item to specific order list


        }

        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.e(TAG , "onChildChanged called");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Firebase equivalent to SQL's `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`.

In Firebase you have to retrieve each item individually. But this is not as slow as you may think, since [Firebase pipelines the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: okay so how i will be needing separate listener to fetch items and then i manually add it under specific order , wouldn't that be cumbersome process ?

Comment: That's subjective, so I'm not sure what you're looking for. If you write the code and it doesn't work, post the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you have code and wonder if it could be simplified, you might want to post that either here or on codereview.stackexchange.com.